# Cannot import gnureadline package in Python3.x (Mac OS)

Tags: python, macos, python-3.5

I have successfully installed gnureadline using both pip (2.x) and pip-3.5. Although importing it in Python2.7 works perfectly, in Python 3.5 it throws the following exception:

```
Python 3.5.1 (default, Jan 31 2016, 04:03:04)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import gnureadline
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gnureadline.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyInt_AsLong
  Referenced from: /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gnureadline.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gnureadline.so
```

The weird thing is that python looks for the package in the Python2.7 path.

The platform is OSX 10.11.3.

Comment: What is the value of `sys.path`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to check your [PYTHONHOME](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHOME) env variable.

check it with `echo $PYTHONHOME`, it should point to `3.5` version ,
 if it's not true, fix it by  the following command
`export PYTHONHOME=/full path to appropriate python libs/`

Answer (score 1):

After checking the sys.path variable as [BasicWolf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/240950/basicwolf) pointed out, I noticed that the 2.7 site packages were included independent of the python version that I run. This happened due to an override of the PYTHONPATH env variable in my .bashrc file:

```
export PYTHONPATH=~/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/
```